# css: aligning span at top of td

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code which looks like the following,

```css
.RegCurrImage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.4) !important;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #003366;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.RegCurrImage span {
    position: relative;
    color: #003366;
    /*line-height:48px;*/
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="RegCurrImage"><span>1</span></div></td>
            <td><span>testing</span><span>testing</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

here my text (`testing`) is appearing at middle I am unable to top align this,

I want to align this span from where my `RegCurrImage` div begins without changing the css of `RegCurrImage`

like the below image[image: THIS]

I tried `verticle-align:top;` but this didn't help either

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` on `td`

```css
td{vertical-align:top;}
.RegCurrImage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.4) !important;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #003366;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.RegCurrImage span {
    position: relative;
    color: #003366;
    /*line-height:48px;*/
    font-size: 45px;
    
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="RegCurrImage"><span>1</span></div></td>
            <td><span>testing</span><span>testing</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, I am setting verticle-align property to span that's way my code didn't worked, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` to second `td`

```css
.RegCurrImage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.4) !important;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid 1px #003366;
    text-align: center !important;
}

.RegCurrImage span {
    position: relative;
    color: #003366;
    /*line-height:48px;*/
    font-size: 45px;
}
td:nth-child(2){
    display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="RegCurrImage"><span>1</span></div></td>
            <td><span>testing</span><span>testing</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

OR     `vertical-align: top;` to second

```css
    .RegCurrImage {
        background-color: rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.4) !important;
        line-height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: solid 1px #003366;
        text-align: center !important;
    }

    .RegCurrImage span {
        position: relative;
        color: #003366;
        /*line-height:48px;*/
        font-size: 45px;
    }
    td:nth-child(2){
          vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><div class="RegCurrImage"><span>1</span></div></td>
                <td><span>testing</span><span>testing</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```